# error when running the py-faster-rcnn demo.py

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe

I clone the py-faster-rcnn and do as the readme.md.
when I run the demo :
./tools/demo.py

```
it show error like that:
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
W0714 20:05:17.716984 10629 _caffe.cpp:139] DEPRECATION WARNING - deprecated use of Python interface
W0714 20:05:17.717007 10629 _caffe.cpp:140] Use this instead (with the named "weights" parameter):
W0714 20:05:17.717011 10629 _caffe.cpp:142] Net('/home/liuyuhang/py-faster-rcnn/models/pascal_voc/VGG16/faster_rcnn_alt_opt/faster_rcnn_test.pt', 1, weights='/home/liuyuhang/py-faster-rcnn/data/faster_rcnn_models/VGG16_faster_rcnn_final.caffemodel')
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/text_format.cc:245] Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 350:21: Message type "caffe.LayerParameter" has no field named "roi_pooling_param".
F0714 20:05:17.718535 10629 upgrade_proto.cpp:88] Check failed: ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param) Failed to parse NetParameter file: /home/liuyuhang/py-faster-rcnn/models/pascal_voc/VGG16/faster_rcnn_alt_opt/faster_rcnn_test.pt
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
```

how can i solve this?

Comment: whats your python version ?

Comment: Did you use the version of Caffe given as a submodule in the py-faster-rcnn repository?

Comment: my python version is the default of ubuntu14.04,which is Python 2.7.13

Comment: I just clone the caffe from github, https://github.com/BVLC/caffe.git 
and move it into caffe-fast-rcnn folder

Comment: I try to clone the external/caffe from the faster-rcnn github

Comment: Use the version of Caffe given in the repository. Many projects add their own code or use features that were later changed or modified in the main Caffe repository. While cloning, use the `--recursive` flag to clone submodules.

Comment: (Aside, if you are replying to comments, use @<user_name> which notifies the original commenter)